# Laravel route model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Hi i have this code from book im learning laravel and mvc

```
Route::model('cat', 'Cat');


Route::get('cats/test', function()
{   
    return "test_working";
});

Route::get('cats/{cat}', function(Cat $cat) {
return View::make('cats.single')
->with('cat', $cat);
});

Route::get('cats/create', function() {
    $cat = new Cat;
    return View::make('cats.edit')
    ->with('cat', $cat)
    ->with('method', 'post');
});
```

if the 2nd route is on 3th drops an NotFoundHttpException 
i know its related with cats/{cat} and model can someone explain why its happens 
of course i can just move the code but i want to know why. Thank you.

Comment: What is the URL that throws the exception?

Comment: Route::get('cats/create', function()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Route::get('cats/{cat}'` will "catch" `/cats/create` because the `{cat}` part in the one route matches anything. No only id's but also `create`. You can either change the order to this to have the more restricted route (`cats/create`) before the less restricted one (`cats/{cat}`) or you can use regex to allow only numbers for `{cat}`:

```
Route::get('cats/{cat}', function(Cat $cat) {
    return View::make('cats.single')
    ->with('cat', $cat);
})->where('cat', '[0-9]+');
```